# Generate random number biased toward a particular number

Tags: python, statistics

I want to generate a random integer within a range but on average I want it to be biased toward a particular number. For example, I want to pick a number from `0-50` `N times` and the average of all the chosen random numbers should be around `20`. I tried to use the `random.normalvariate` function in python and casting it from `float` to `int` but I'm not sure if it's a proper solution. I set the `mean` to `20` but I am not sure what the `standard deviation` should be in order to make sure that on average we pick `20` from the range.

```
r = int(random.normalvariate(20, st_dev???)) 
r = 50 if r > 50 else r # clamp
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several choices, but one discrete random distribution that satisfies the properties is [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). In particular, a binomial distribution with parameters `n=50` and `p=0.4` is distributed on `{0, ..., 50}` and has mean `20` (because `n * p = 20`). Also its distribution is close to a normal distribution (loosely by central limit theorem).

```py
from scipy.stats import binom

r = binom.rvs(50, 0.4, size=1000)
print(r) # [20 16 24 24 18 21 21 25 27 22 22 22 20 18 23 ... (a sample)
print(sum(r) / len(r)) # 20.022 (sample mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a mean of 20 is the only requirement for pseudo-random integers generated from 1 to 50, this simple generator based on `random.random()` will meet it:

```
        import random
        def biased_uniform(n, invert_threshold):
            u = random.random()
            if u > 0.5 and random.random() > invert_threshold:
                u = 1 - u
            v = int(50 * u + 0.5) + 1
            v = 1 if v == 0 else v
            return v
        total, n = 0, 1000000
        for i in range(n):
            v = biased_uniform(50, 0.52)
            total += v
        mean = total / n
        print(f"mean {mean}")
```

You can tune the mean by adjusting the `invert_threshold` in the semi-open interval [0.0, 1.0).